# Linear optimization in CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I am trying to code this constraints:

`n[a][t] >= sum (k == t + 1 - la/Va .. t) u[a][t]`

where la, Va are given, a = 1..7, t = 1..100

This is my code, but it didn't work!

```
forall (a in links, t in time_step)
    volume[a][t] >= sum (i in k..t : k == t + 1 - (a.length/a.speed)) inflow[a][i];
```

How can I define "k" when it is the function of index "t".
Could anyone please help me to correct it?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, post your task, code, errors, input and expected output as plain text.

Comment: This is my first time asking question here so thank you for your comment, Sanya.

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you write something like this?

```
forall (a in links, t in time_step)
    volume[a][t] >= sum (i in t + 1 - ftoi(ceil((a.length/a.speed)))..t ) inflow[a][i];
```

Comment: Plus similar question at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/495436/sum-in-cplex/